# Read_csv from pandas with different column length

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trying to read a csv file with pandas lib in python, but I have a problem...
My CSV file is a "sensor reader" and can vary the column length (sometimes 147, sometimes 148, and this happen in the middle of the file too). Besides that, the first 4 lines of my csv file have junk information, and i have to skip.
My problem is: how to read this file since I need to jump the initial lines, and read the final lines even the column length is bigger than the initial column length ?

```
jump_initial_lines_length = 4

data = pd.read_csv(ARQUIVO, keep_default_na=False, skiprows=4, na_filter=False, header=jump_initial_lines_length)
```

I have an example of my csv file:

```
0  File name: bananas

1  Date: 12/12/1212

2  Author: Jvff

3  Version: 1.0.3

4  Fruits  Cities  Names  Cars  Colors

5  Apple  NY       Joe    Logan   White

6 Bananas LA       Bob    Renegade  Black

7  Fruits  Cities  Names  Cars  Colors  **Country**

8  Apple  NY       Joe    Logan   White  **EUA**

9 Bananas LA       Bob    Renegade  Black  **Canada**
```

You can see in the line 7, the new "country column"...

**Conditions:

~> the line of Country Column is unknown (i don't know when the country column starts in the csv file)

~> i just catch the csv file from another dpt... so, it's impossible to filter that in the production of the csv file**

Comment: Is it only two different types, i.e. `Fruits Cities Names Cars Colors` and `Fruits Cities Names Cars Colors Country`? If so, I would first split this text file at the line `Fruits Cities Names Cars Colors Country` and then read it as two separate CSVs. As for skipping the beginning lines, read_csv has a argument for that, just check the docs.

Comment: but, how can i split the file if i don't know the line when the "country column" shows up ? i can't open the csv file to read and search the line because pandas return a error like:

"pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 5, saw 2"

Comment: Read it as a text file and loop through each line until you find that line, then split the file. Do this with regular python file handling not pandas. Pandas only comes in once you've split the file.

Comment: What's your delimiter in the csv/txt file? do you have row numbers in the file too?

Comment: @Datanovice nop, depends the time of the test realized, like, 1 minute of the test is equals +/- 90 lines...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you will have to check the len of each line of your csv file.
Maybe something like that can do the Job:

```
import csv

with open(filename1, 'r') as f1:
    csvlines = csv.reader(f1, delimiter=',')
    for lineNum, line in enumerate(csvlines):
        insert_at = 7  # index at which you want to insert item
        line_modified = line[:]   # created copy of list "line" as "line_modified"

        if lineNum>=4 and len(line)==127:
            #Add a Country column if not in header of .csv file
            line_modified [insert_at:insert_at] = "Country"

        elif len(line)==127:
            #Add an empty cell if only 127 elements in the line
            line_modified [insert_at:insert_at] = ""

        list_prepared.append(line_modified)


    df = pd.DataFrame(list_prepared[1:], columns=list_prepared[0])
```